# Sending USDTC to a new Tron address in testnet --"Unrecorded Token"

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb

I have a newly generated TRON address in testnet - Shasta. I'm trying to send USDC to it, from a faucet - usdcfaucet.com. While on an Ethereum testnet it'll get received fine, if I send it there, on TRON there's been ocurring an error

"Unrecorded Token"

And my balance has never increased.

[image]

What's the matter?

Does TRON require activatation, or explicit creation on a token account, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry, your transaction executed successfully. The explorer just marked the token as scam token, therefore, the received tokens were hidden from the wallet.
However, your wallet still received those tokens successfully.
You can check by either sending those tokens to another account or just clicking at the transaction hash to view more details. In the case you click the transaction hash, a warning popup will appear, so just proceed.

---

For more info, the contract of that token is [TFGBSrddCjLJAwuryZ9DUxtEmKv13BPjnh](https://shasta.tronscan.org/#/contract/TFGBSrddCjLJAwuryZ9DUxtEmKv13BPjnh). And fastest way to check if your account has those tokens is to call `balanceOf` function via the explorer. This function is just a read function, therefore, there is no gas cost and no wallet connecting needed.
The demonstration is in the below image, where I check if your account has 30 USDC (the decimals is 6).

- [POC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEG5V.png)
- [The url to the smart contract code](https://shasta.tronscan.org/#/contract/TFGBSrddCjLJAwuryZ9DUxtEmKv13BPjnh/code)